# Deleting Active Leaderboards and Achievements

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I know that Apple says you cannot delete leaderboards and achievements once they are active. Is there a way to get them to not show up on an updated version of the game? Or do I have to delete my app and remake everything? There has to be a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaderboards can't be deleted once they are used in a live app, therefore you will need to create a new app if you wish to 'remove' a leaderboard.

> You can’t delete a leaderboard after the leaderboard appears in a live version of the app.

<sup>Source: [Game Center Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Leaderboards/Leaderboards.html)</sup>

Comment: So, if I delete the current app, then create a new one, what are the repercussions? What will happen to my users? Will I be able to use the same name for my app?

Comment: @Jake The app won't show as an update to current users and they will have to uninstall the app and install the new one from the App Store. As for other possible repercussions, I'm not sure as I've never done it myself—try a search and a new question if necessary so others see this.